# EF Core 5 - Extension method on filter include

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying the new, awesome and finally implemented "Filtered Include" on EF Core 5 (preview 3).

This code is perfectly working

```
var categoriesWithActiveProducts = await _context.Categories.Include(x => x.Products.Where(y => y.IsActive)).ToListAsync();
```

Well, now I'd like to use an extension method to make the code more intuitive, so

```
var categoriesWithActiveProducts = await _context.Categories.Include(x => x.Products.ActiveQueryFilter()).ToListAsync();

public static IEnumerable<Product> ActiveQueryFilter(this ICollection<Product> source)
{
    return source.Where(x => x.IsActive).AsEnumerable();
}
```

But I get the error below

> System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'x.Products.ActiveQueryFilter()' is invalid inside Include operation. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types use cast, e.g. 't => ((Derived)t).MyProperty' or 'as' operator, e.g. 't => (t as Derived).MyProperty'. Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Logical reason: EF doesn't know what `ActiveQueryFilter` does. You can return any `IEnumerable<Product>` from it. The technical reason is that EF knows how to translate expressions, not custom methods as `ActiveQueryFilter`. Instead, you could store the expression `y => y.IsActive` in a variable somewhere and feed that to the `Where` clause.

Comment: From [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/querying/related-data#filtered-include): _Supported operations are: Where, OrderBy, OrderByDescending, ThenBy, ThenByDescending, Skip, and Take_
I guess custom extension methods are not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to use a static method in an EF query. [The documentation explains why](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation-in-the-top-level-projection)

Basically they can cause memory leaks and unexpected behaviour